# Ansible: Obtain api_token from gce_container_cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I launch the GCP cluster with no problem but I do not know how to get k8s ansible module to work. I would prefer to get the api_key to authenticate into k8s module.

My playbook is the following.

```
- name: Hello k8s
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Create a cluster
      register: cluster
      gcp_container_cluster:
        name: thecluster
        initial_node_count: 1
        master_auth:
          username: admin
          password: TheRandomPassword
        node_config:
          machine_type: g1-small
          disk_size_gb: 10
          oauth_scopes:
            - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute"
            - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only"
            - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write"
            - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring"
        zone: europe-west3-c
        project:  second-network-255214 
        auth_kind: serviceaccount
        service_account_file: "{{ lookup('env', 'GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS') }}"
        state: present 
    - name: Show results
      debug: var=cluster
    - name: Create temporary file for CA
      tempfile:
        state: file
        suffix: build
      register: ca_crt
    - name: Save content to file
      copy: 
        content: "{{ cluster.masterAuth.clusterCaCertificate |b64decode }}"
        dest: "{{ ca_crt.path }}"
    - name: Create a k8s namespace
      k8s:
        host: "https://{{ cluster.endpoint }}"
        ca_cert: "{{ ca_crt.path }}"
        api_key: "{{ cluster.HOW_I_GET_THE_API_KEY}}" <<<-- Here is what I want!!!
        name: testing
        api_version: v1
        kind: Namespace
        state: present
```

Any idea?

Comment: I would expect it's in `cluster.masterAuth`, and I see you already `debug:`-ed it, so did you not find the `token` in that data structure?

Comment: That's correct. I implemented the same tasks in terraform using google_client_config. I supposed there would a simikar module in ansible.

Comment: I have tried with an empty map of master_auth and removing master_auth entry. Maybe it could be done with the k8s_auth module but I do not know how to configure it.

Comment: No, I mean `cluster.masterAuth` already contains `clusterCaCertificate` -- what else does `cluster.masterAuth` contain?

Comment: If I pass username or password in the master_auth block, I obtain them (username and password) in masterAuth, in addition to the clusterCaCertificate. For authentication, I think that username and password are not needed. The ideal would be to get an access_token for the GCP serviceaccount. Additionally, I thing that the access_token is not only valid in the cluster context but valid wide along the whole GCP. So is not related to gcp_container_cluster but there should be a gcp_iam_service_account_token or an oauth module that maybe do the job.

Comment: Links to the GCP JWT: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 and https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Answer (score 0):

I founded a workaround that is to call gcloud directly:

```
    - name: Get JWT
      command: gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
      register: api_key
```

Obviously, I needed to:

- Install GCloud
- Redefine the envvar with the auth.json to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

The task calls gcloud directly to obtain the token, so no need to generate the token. I will try to add to add this feature as a module into ansible for better interoperability with kubernetes.

Once obtained it is possible to call k8s module like this:

```
    - name: Create ClusterRoleBinding
      k8s:
        state: present
        host: "https://{{ cluster.endpoint }}"
        ca_cert: "{{ ca_crt.path }}"
        api_version: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
        api_key: "{{ api_key.stdout }}"
        definition:
          kind: ClusterRoleBinding
          metadata:
            name: kube-system_default_cluster-admin
          subjects:
          - kind: ServiceAccount
            name: default # Name is case sensitive
            namespace: kube-system
          roleRef:
            kind: ClusterRole
            name: cluster-admin
            apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/gcp_container_cluster_module.html#return-values), `masterAuth` contains two other fields, `clientCertificate` and `clientKey` that correspond to the [`client_cert:` and `client_key:` parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/k8s_module.html#parameters), respectively. From that point, you can authenticate to your cluster's endpoint as `cluster-admin` using the very, very strong credentials of the private key, and from that point use the same `k8s:` task to provision yourself a `cluster-admin` `ServiceAccount` token if you wish to do that.

You can also apparently use `masterAuth.username` and `masterAuth.password` in the `username:` and `password:` parameters of `k8s:`, too, which should be just as safe since the credentials travel over HTTPS, but you seemed like you were more interested in a higher entropy authentication solution.